# Calling AWS functions from an Apache server

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, permissions

I have a Apache server and at certain events I want it to call Amazon web services (AWS) functions. Specifically, it must upload a file to an S3 bucket. When I log in via the terminal and run the commands as root, everything works fine and the file gets uploaded. However, when the event is generated by Apache (I checked that the user is Apache using exec('whoami')) I get permission warnings in the application logs. I get these warnings even before calling any functions, it fails at the include line:

> include 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

I've changed the owner of the AWS files to apache and also placed the files in various locations, including in the same directory as the function that calls the AWS code, as well as a user's home directory, without any success.

The specific warning is:

> server [warning] [-@127.0.0.1] (7245) *Warning: include(): Failed
>   opening 'aws/aws-autoloader.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in MyHandlers.php on
>   line 4

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this? I've been struggling with this for days now, so any tip/suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there an `aws` subdirectory in your script's current working directory? e.g. if your script is in `/foo/bar/script.php`, then your aws stuff would have to be in `/foo/bar/aws/aws-autoloader.php` (or at least have that sort of thing SOMEWHERE in php's script_path setting).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how it currently is. I also tried including it using the full path.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you using Composer to manage your project dependencies/autoloading? Secondly, what if you use an absolute path, e.g., include \_\_DIR\_\_ . '/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I'll try the __DIR__ method. I first tried it with Composer, but it didn't work. I then downloaded the zip and that's what I'm using now. I find it easier to work with the zip file as I don't fully understand what Composer is doing.